# Symfony check if user's email changed while logged in

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a test project where I made a simple login form configuring `security.yml`. I learned that `serialize` and `unserialize` functions in entity, load and get `User` instance from session and compare id, username and password with data from DB. When one of these parameters is not equal, user get logged out.

```
public function serialize() {
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password
        ));
    }

public function unserialize($serialized) {
    list(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
```

Now I would even check if email is changed while the user is logged in, if so log out. I tried to add `$this->email` to `serialize` and `unserialize` functions, but it doesn't care about it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @gp_sflover I already read about `EquatableInterface` but how can I compare `$user` email in database? I can't find a right way to send queries from Entity or use its repository..

Comment: I added an answer. Let me know :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a [User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-provider) that implement the `UserProviderInterface` and you need to compare some sensible user data stored in the user session instance from which stored in database, the most simple way is to implement the `EquatableInterface` in your `User` class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;

class User implements EquatableInterface
{
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->email <--- add the email to serialized data
            #$this->account->getEmail() <--- you can also add the email from an association
            ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->email <--- add the email to unserialize method
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface $user
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user):bool
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }
        # here you make the email comparison
        if ($this->email !== $user->getEmail()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
     }
}
```

In that way **you don't need to query the DB** because you take advantage of your user provider that refresh automatically the $user object on each request through:

```
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }
```

Comment: So simple, so powerful. Thank you so much. Could you explain me also in which case `$user instanceof User === false`?

Comment: @DrKey I don't sure to understand what you mean with "_in which case_...", but as obvious, you need to maintain data consistency and avoid to pass some "unsupported" user object when you use that method directly.